# Incorrect syntax in where

Tags: sql

Below is my query which I am trying to write. but I am getting an error saying incorrect syntax near where

```
SELECT
    [p.ProjectId],
    SUM(pf.size),
    COUNT(pr.ServerGroupId) AS [UnRestrictedFacility],
    CASE   
       WHEN COUNT(ps.CreatedBy) > 0 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
    END 
FROM
    Project p 
INNER JOIN
    ProjectFile pf 
INNER JOIN
    ProjectPartlink ppl ON pf.ProjectPartlinkId = ppl.ProjectPartlinkid  
                        AND ppl.ProjectId = p.projectid 
INNER JOIN
    ProjectRestriction pr ON pr.projectid = p.projectid 
INNER JOIN
    ProjectPreseed ps ON ps.projectid = p.projectid 
WHERE
    p.projectid = @projectid
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have `[p].[ProjectId]` instead, as the select list's first item.

Comment: What rdbms are you using? Unless it's an older version of mysql, the error probably comes from a missing `group by`. Even if you do use an rdbms that allows aggregation without a `group by`, you should add it for reliable results. Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

here is the error it seems :

```
From Project p inner join
ProjectFile pf inner join
```

it should be

```
From Project p inner join
ProjectFile pf on p.id = pf.id inner join
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is a bit misleading:

```
From Project p inner join
   ProjectFile pf inner join
   ProjectPartlink ppl
```

You are missing the `ON` of the first join.

**edit:**

You are also using aggregation functions without a `group by`. Far as I know, that's only allowed by older versions of mysql. If you use aggregation you must use a `group by` clause to get reliable results. You don't mention what rdbms you use, but this is also a likely cause for the error.

Answer (score 1):

First, cleaning up and having a well formatted SQL will help you in the long run.  Always put your "ON" clauses with the respective join so you know you did not forget something and have a Cartesian result down the road.  Also, my personal preference is to always list the ON clause with the leftSideAlias.column = rightSideAlias.column.  It also helps to show the relationship between table A->B->C, etc..  You actually DID have all the pieces to the query, I just reorganized them.  Notice the readability from one table to the next too.

```
SELECT
      p.ProjectId,
      sum(pf.size),
      count(pr.ServerGroupId) UnRestrictedFacility,
      CASE when count(ps.CreatedBy) > 0 then 1 Else 0 END CreatedCounter
   From 
      Project p 
         inner join ProjectPartlink ppl  
            on p.projectid = ppl.ProjectId
            inner join ProjectFile pf 
               on ppl.ProjectPartlinkid = pf.ProjectPartlinkId
         inner join ProjectRestriction pr
            on p.projectid = pr.projectid
         inner join ProjectPreseed ps   
            on p.projectid = ps.projectid 
   where 
      p.projectid = @parmProjectid
```

Finally, your WHERE clause.  You had @ProjectID which I have known to cause confusion when supplying a variable.  If there is no variable by that name, but there is a column by that name, it appears to resolve to the column name.  To prevent that, I like to explicitly tack-on some sort of prefix, such a above from @ProjectID to @parmProjectID so I KNOW it is coming from some parameter and not a mistaken column name reference.

Answer (score 0):

And this should work as well, due to default order of operations

```
   From Project p 
   inner join ProjectFile pf 
   inner join ProjectPartlink ppl 
   on pf.ProjectPartlinkId=ppl.ProjectPartlinkid  
   on ppl.ProjectId=p.projectid
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
SELECT
    [p.ProjectId],
    SUM(pf.size),
    COUNT(pr.ServerGroupId) AS [UnRestrictedFacility],
    CASE   
       WHEN COUNT(ps.CreatedBy) > 0 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
    END 
FROM
    Project p 
INNER JOIN
    ProjectFile pf on pf.Id = p.tId
INNER JOIN
    ProjectPartlink ppl ON pf.ProjectPartlinkId = ppl.ProjectPartlinkid  
                        AND ppl.ProjectId = p.projectid 
INNER JOIN
    ProjectRestriction pr ON pr.projectid = p.projectid 
INNER JOIN
    ProjectPreseed ps ON ps.projectid = p.projectid 
WHERE
    p.projectid = @projectid
```